# SQL join with aggregated data

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have two SQL tables.

USERS

```
ID   |  USERNAME
001  |  Tom 
002  |  Jane
003  |  Peter
004  |  Mariah
```

PRODUCTS

```
ID   |   PR_NAME   |  USERID
01   |   Apple     |   002
02   |   Pear      |   001
03   |   Tomato    |   002
04   |   Apple     |   003
05   |   Tomato    |   001
06   |   Apple     |   001
```

If I select "Apple" in a form/list/app I want to see who bought "Apple" AND how many products those persons bought:

```
USERID | USERNAME | NUM_PRODUCTS_BOUGHT
001    |  Tom     |          3
002    |  Jane    |          2
003    |  Peter   |          1
```

What I tried is

```
SELECT 
   USERS.ID, USERS.USERNAME, 
   COUNT(PRODUCTS.PR_NAME) AS NUM_PRODUCTS_BOUGHT 
FROM 
   USERS 
LEFT JOIN 
   PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTS.USERID = USERS.ID 
WHERE 
   PRODUCTS.PR_NAME = "Apple" 
GROUP BY 
   USERS.ID
```

but it gives me wrong numbers from NUM_ALL (1) like

```
ID     | USERNAME | NUM_PRODUCTS_BOUGHT
001    |  Tom     |          1
002    |  Jane    |          1
003    |  Peter   |          1
```

I can get this result in 3 ways but cannot get what I want.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: What is wrong with those results?  Tom, Jane, and Peter did indeed each buy one apple according to your sample data.

Comment: Giving your condition PR_NAME = "Apple", I don't see how the answer is wrong?

Comment: It's PDO. They bought one apple in which you are right but I want to know how many fruits they bought each. Tom bought an apple so he must be in the result table, but he also bought a pear and a tomato. So he bought 3 fruits all in all. That's what I need.

Comment: @erdomester . . . Then remove the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try a having clause. I haven't tested this, but it should work:

```
SELECT 
   USERS.ID, USERS.USERNAME, 
   COUNT(PRODUCTS.PR_NAME) AS NUM_PRODUCTS_BOUGHT 
FROM 
   USERS 
LEFT JOIN 
   PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTS.USERID = USERS.ID 
GROUP BY 
   USERS.ID
HAVING 
   SUM(CASE WHEN PRODUCTS.PR_NAME = "Apple" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you are missing "Mariah", this is because the `where` clause is undoing the `left outer join`.  Move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.USERNAME, COUNT(p.PR_NAME) AS NUM_PRODUCTS_BOUGHT 
FROM USERS u LEFT JOIN 
     PRODUCTS p
     ON p.USERID = u.ID AND
        p.PR_NAME = 'Apple'
GROUP BY u.ID;
```

NOTE:  In some databases, you would need to include `u.USERNAME` in the `group by` clause.  However, assuming that `USERS.ID` is unique, this usage is consistent with the ANSI standard.

Comment: I am not missing Mariah as she did not bought any apples

Answer (score 0):

You can think about it in layers...

First, you have a product

```
--q1
select * from PRODUCTS where PR_NAME = "Apple"
```

Then you want to know users that brought that product

```
--q2
select * from users where
id in (
--q1
select USERID from PRODUCTS where PR_NAME = "Apple"
)
```

Now for a user you want to know how many products he/she bought

```
--q3
select userid, count(id) cnt from PRODUCT group by userid
```

And finally you want to combine output from q2 and q3:

```
select u.id, u.USERNAME, cnt.cnt from users u inner join 
(    --q3
select userid, count(id) cnt from PRODUCT  group by userid
) cnt on u.ID = cnt.userid
where
u.id in (
--q1
select USERID from PRODUCTS where PR_NAME = "Apple"
)
```

optimization:

```
select u.id, u.USERNAME, cnt.cnt from users u inner join 
(    --q3
select userid, count(id) cnt from PRODUCT  group by userid
) cnt on u.ID = cnt.userid
inner join product p on u.id = p.userid
where
p.pr_name = 'Apple'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT U.ID, U.USERNAME, COUNT(P2.PR_NAME) NUM_PRODUCTS_BOUGHT
FROM USERS U
  JOIN PRODUCTS P1
    ON U.ID = P1.USERID
  JOIN PRODUCTS P2
    ON P1.USERID = P2.USERID
WHERE P1.PR_NAME = 'Apple'
GROUP BY U.ID, U.USERNAME
```

Here is the **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad7dc/2)** for SQL Server.

Comment: I would give you the points as you were the fastest and +1 for the sql fiddle. However, @outis nihil's code is much easier to understand.